# Float right a fixed div and rotate it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to rotate this div, fix it and float it to the RIGHT like this [jsbin.com/ujebik/1][1] but it don't completely float to the RIGHT

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
     ROTATE THIS TEXT
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .logo {
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
right: 0;
z-index: 100; 
width: 250px; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  font-size:20px;
 background-color:green 
}
```

UPDATE:

want this:

[image]

but Have this:

[image]

Comment: include your css and html to your question.

Comment: It's the same code of the jsbin, so really it's difficult to understand...I think it's better if you attach a stamp of what you have and what you expect

Comment: @AlessandroMassa I've just update the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add transform-origin: 100% 100%; to make the div rotate around its lower right corner instead of its center (http://jsbin.com/iniweq/2/)

Comment: Hello, Well I was trying to float the div to the LEFT (this time) but I got the same problem I got before: it don't float completely to the left. Can you help me on this again please.

Comment: You need to set the transform origin to the left top or left bottom corner, depending on the direction of the rotation. This is `transform-origin: 0% 0%` and `transform-origin: 0% 100%`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing what you are trying to do is have the element on the left? If this is the case then you need to change your CSS to

```
 .logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100; 
  width: 250px; 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  font-size:20px;
  background-color:green 
  }
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Er3yL/

Or if what you are trying to say is that you want to 'float' it to the extreme RIGHT, then I am guessing that the parent element for .logo is not stretched to 100% of the window. Either you can correct that or if you want to keep it that way then you can add a negative value to right, like this

```
 .logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: -20px;
  z-index: 100; 
  width: 250px; 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  font-size:20px;
  background-color:green 
  }
```

Comment: @AsmeJust Then the second block of my answer applies. :) Hope it helped.

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the parent element for .logo. How wide is that? Did you increase the value of right ?